# Datepicker startdate/enddate difference exclude weekends and populate input

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to work out the differnce in days (excluding weekends) between a startdate and enddate selected by the user using datepicker.

This number of days then wants to be inputted into the #days input.
Does anybody know where im going wrong?

```
// do initialization here
$("#startdate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
var startdate = $("#startdate").val();
var enddate =   $("#enddate").val();                
var weekend_count = 0;
                        for (i = startdate.valueOf(); i <= enddate.valueOf(); i+= 86400000){
                        var temp = new Date(i);
                            if (temp.getDay() == 0 || temp.getDay() == 6) {
                                weekend_count++;
                            }
                    }
                    $("#days").val((startdate - enddate) / 86400000 - weekend_count);
                    $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                },              
                minDate: '+1d',         
                maxDate: '+' + (DAY_DIFFERENCE + 1) + 'd'
    });



// do initialization here
$("#enddate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
});
```

**EDIT - Im getting there on my own, does anybody have any input? this following solution kind of works (but im struggling with the php variable - how can i include the var in a php date function). the isNAN if for opera and old XP machines.**

```
    //holidays
    var natDays = [
      [1, 1, 'uk'],
      [12, 25, 'uk'],
      [12, 26, 'uk']
    ];


    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
        var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        if (noWeekend[0]) {
            return nationalDays(date);
        } else {
            return noWeekend;
        }
    }
    function nationalDays(date) {
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }



// do initialization here
$("#startdate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $("#enddate").datepicker("option","minDate",selectedDate );
            },              
            minDate: '+1d',         
            maxDate: '+' + DAY_DIFFERENCE + 'd'
});


// do initialization here
$("#enddate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $d1 = $('#startdate').val();
            $d2 = $('#enddate2').val();

            console.log($d1);
            console.log($d2);

            $d1p = Date.parse($d1)
            $d2p = Date.parse($d2)

            console.log($d1p);
            console.log($d2p);

            $myDateParts1 = $d1.split("-");
            $myDateParts2 = $d2.split("-");

            console.log($myDateParts1);
            console.log($myDateParts2);

            $myNewDate1 = new Date($myDateParts1[2], $myDateParts1[1], $myDateParts1[0]);
            $myNewDate2 = new Date($myDateParts2[2], $myDateParts2[1], $myDateParts2[0]);

            console.log($myNewDate1);
            console.log($myNewDate2);

            $d1flip= $myNewDate1; 
            $d2flip= $myNewDate2; 

            console.log($d1flip);
            console.log($d2flip);

            // For Opera and older winXP IE n such
            if (isNaN($d1p)) { 
                $d1p  = Date.parse($d1flip);
            }
            if (isNaN($d2p)) { 
                $d2p  = Date.parse($d2flip);
            }


                var weekend_count = 0;
                    for (i = $d1p.valueOf(); i <= $d2p.valueOf(); i+= 86400000){
                    var temp = new Date(i);
                        if (temp.getDay() == 0 || temp.getDay() == 6) {
                            weekend_count++;
                        }
                }
                $('#days').val((Math.abs(($d2p-$d1p)/86400000) - weekend_count));
            }           
});
```

Comment: Can you describe what is going wrong with the result of your script?

Comment: i have edited the question with the current solution for my problem, how can i do a php date from the javascript var? $d1new= '<?php echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime(d1)) ?>';

Comment: console.log - 18-09-2012
19-09-2012
NaN
NaN
["18", "09", "2012"]
["19", "09", "2012"]
Thu Oct 18 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 {}
Fri Oct 19 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 {}
Thu Oct 18 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 {}
Fri Oct 19 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 {}
0 ------------- why is this returning at october?